# How to define an object apparently implemented as a static read-only field? (Using iText 7 to convert multi-page TIFF to PDF)

Tags: c#, static, itext, variable-initialization

I'm writing a program in PowerShell that uses iText 7 DLLs. I use a DLL disassembly tool, IText DLLs, and iText sample/example C# code and convert the sample C# code to PowerShell code.

For example:

**iText Sample code**

```
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(dest);
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(writer);
```

**PowerShell**

```
[itext.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter]$newPdfWriter = New-Object itext.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter(($outputFolderPath + "\" + $newPdfName))
[itext.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument]$newPdfDoc = New-Object itext.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument($newPdfWriter)
```

There is a line of code in some example iText c# code that I don't understand. `See Figure 1 below`. Although I converted the code to the right of assignment operator ok, I can't figure out the code to the left of the assignment operator. I thought I just needed to define an object of type `URL` and assign the results of the call to `UrlUtil.toURL` to the `URL` object. But, my approach fails. *(Note: `UrlUtil.toURL` is a method in an `iText` class and returns a `Microsoft [System.Uri]` object and `TEST3` is a string constant, i.e, a path name to an image file).*

```
//Figure 1
URL url3 = UrlUtil.toURL(TEST3);
```

I looked up `URL` in the `iText API index` (http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext7/latest/). It tells me that `URL` is a `static variable` in the class `com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfName`. I disassembled `itext.kernel.dll` that I'm using and I see what looks like an example of variable initialization: `public static readonly PdfName URL = PdfName.CreateDirectName(nameof (URL));` See `Figure 2` below for context.

In PowerShell, if `URL` were a class, I'd define a `URL` object like this: `[itext.kernel.pdf.PdfName.URL]$url = {a System.Uri object variable}`. But, `URL` is a `static, readonly` variable, not a class. When I run this PowerShell code, I get `Unable to find type [itext.kernel.pdf.PdfName.URL]` which makes sense since `URL` is not a class. Also, when I model this fragment in Visual Studio, I get an error: `"Static readonly field cannot be assigned to (except in a static constructor or a variable initializer)"` (see screenshot with c# code). I've researched this error but don't understand it either.

[image: screen shot of my small c# model showing]

So, the c# code `URL url3 = UrlUtil.toURL(TEST3);` looks like a `System.Uri` object is being assigned to an object of type `URL`.

What is actually happening here at run time in the iText C# sample code?

How do I define an object of type `URL`?

```
//Figure 2
namespace iText.Kernel.Pdf
{
    public class PdfName : PdfPrimitiveObject, IComparable<PdfName>
    {
       .
       .
       public static readonly PdfName URL = PdfName.CreateDirectName(nameof (URL));
       protected internal string value;
       .
       .

       private static PdfName CreateDirectName(string name)
       {
           return new PdfName(name, true);
       }

       public PdfName(string value)
       {
           this.value = value;
       }

       private PdfName(string value, bool directOnly) : base(directOnly)
       {
           this.value = value;
       }

       public PdfName(byte[] content) : base(content)
       {
       }

       private PdfName()
       {
       }

       .
       .
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you disassemble when the source code is freely available on GitHub?

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse: I'm in an enclave (not connected to internet). I have the DLLs and a disassembler, so it's just easier because I typically only need to verify class names and method signatures. I don't need to dig through all the painful details in the source code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, it may be that the line of code in question (`URL url3 = UrlUtil.toURL(TEST3);`) in the iText tutorial (https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/chapter-3) may be incorrect or deprecated. The call to `UrlUtil.toURL(TEST3)` returns type `System.Uri` and the method `CreateSource` accepts a `System.Uri`, so the use of the type `URL` variable (`url3` in the example) is not needed.

```
// iText Tutorial
URL url3 = UrlUtil.toURL(TEST3);

IRandomAccessSource ras3 = new RandomAccessSourceFactory().createSource(url3);

RandomAccessFileOrArray raf3 = new RandomAccessFileOrArray(ras3);

int pages3 = TiffImageData.getNumberOfPages(raf3);

for (int i = 1; i <= pages3; i++) 
{
    img = new Image(
    ImageDataFactory.createTiff(url3, true, i, true));
    document.add(img);
}

document.close();
```

This code works to convert a multi-page TIF to a PDF

```
using iText.IO.Font;
using iText.IO.Image;
using iText.IO.Source;
using iText.IO.Util;
using iText.Kernel.Font;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf;
using iText.Layout;
using iText.Layout.Element;
using iText.Layout.Properties;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace x_console
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter("C:\\Users\\Bill\\Desktop\\out.pdf");
            PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
            Document document = new Document(pdf);

            Uri tiffFqn = UrlUtil.ToURL("C:\\Users\\Bill\\Desktop\\Multipage Test Image.tif");
            IRandomAccessSource iRandomAccessSource = new RandomAccessSourceFactory().CreateSource(tiffFqn);
            RandomAccessFileOrArray randomAccessFileOrArray = new RandomAccessFileOrArray(iRandomAccessSource);

            int tiffPageCount = TiffImageData.GetNumberOfPages(randomAccessFileOrArray);

            for (int i = 1; i <= tiffPageCount; i++)
            {
                Image tiffPage = new Image(ImageDataFactory.CreateTiff(tiffFqn, true, i, true));
                document.Add(tiffPage);
            }

            document.Close();
        }
    }
}
```